# Plotting value and char over the last bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm stuck with the problem below.

What I would like to achieve:

- Indicator which shows the diff. from 200 EMA in percentages. [solved]
- Add a char (arrow pointing to the bar) over/under the last bar (depending on whether it is a positive or negative value)
- Add a text over/under the last bar with the actual value of the bar

I tried with plotchar and I managed to add the arrows to all bar, but I failed to filter them to show only at the last bar (show_last=1 was not accepted as argument).

I tried to add "text=variable" but Pine accepts only literal string there. I tried tostring(value) but was not accepted.

My code so far which works fine:

```
//
study("Percent diff. from 200 day EMA", shorttitle="% From EMA", overlay=true, precision=2)

dif200 = (close - (ema(close,200))) * 100 / ema(close,200)

plot(dif200, "Diff. from 200", color=#2196f399, linewidth=2, title="From 200", style=columns)
plot(dif200, "Actual value", color=#2196f399, trackprice=true, linewidth=1, transp=10, offset=-9999)

hline(0, color=red, title="Zero line", linestyle=solid, linewidth=2)
```

What should be my next step?

Thank you for your kind help!
Regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. Not possible to plot something on the chart pane if the script is on a separate pane. The single option is to use `barcolor` function.
3. Not possible in pine v1. You should use the latest version of the pinescript `//@version=4`. To plot a dynamic value you have to use `label.new` + `tostring` functions as in the example below. To be able to plot the same dynamic label on the chart pane you have to create a separate script and load it on the chart.

---

```
//@version=4
study("Percent diff. from 200 day EMA", shorttitle="% From EMA", overlay=false, precision=2)

dif200 = (close - (ema(close,200))) * 100 / ema(close,200)

plot(dif200, "Diff. from 200", color=#2196f399, linewidth=2, title="From 200", style=plot.style_columns)
plot(dif200, "Actual value", color=#2196f399, trackprice=true, linewidth=1, transp=10, offset=-9999)

hline(0, color=color.red, title="Zero line", linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=2)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, dif200, tostring(dif200), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, #2196f399, label.style_label_left, color.white)
```

Comment: This is what I tried at the beginning, but I received the following error. no viable alternative at input 'if'. Try to add line '//@version=2' to the top of your script Changing to version 4 did not solve this. And the error occurs even if I try to plot the label on the same pane.

Comment: Example in my answer compiles without any problem. Changed the default overlay to `false`. What compilation error do you see?

Comment: This is the error message: no viable alternative at input 'if'.

Comment: Looks like you partially copied the code that I provided in my answer, I checked it one more time and it compiles without any error.

Comment: Interesting. If I copy only the last two lines of your code it does not work, I copied all of the code now it's working.

Anyway, thank you for your (patient) help! :)